# I cannot pass the value from the button to the entity

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create a test mechanism, after ticking the right option, I want to save this option to the db via my model, but I can't map the value from the JavaScript to my model. How can I do that?

```
@model Exam.Models.ViewModels.QuestionMakerViewModel
<table class="table-borderless" id="s1">
<tbody>
    <form asp-action="QuestionMaker" asp-controller="Teacher" method="post">
    <tr>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Question 1</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for=@Model.Question id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="mt-3" colspan="2">
            <table class="table-borderless">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="A" type="button" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">A</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer1 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="B" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">B</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer2 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="C" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">C</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer3 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" onclick="clickSub()" class="btn btn-success" asp-action="QuestionMaker" asp-controller="Teacher" formmethod="post">Kaydet</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</tbody>
```

Here I got the results from the button id with javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickFunc(answerId) {
    @Model.TrueAnswer=answerId;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use a hidden input to keep the value of `@Model.TrueAnswer`,and then when click the button,change the value of the hidden input,and submit the form to action:

```
@model Exam.Models.ViewModels.QuestionMakerViewModel
<table class="table-borderless" id="s1">
<tbody>
    <form id="myForm" asp-action="QuestionMaker" asp-controller="Teacher" method="post">
    <tr>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Question 1</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" asp-for=@Model.Question id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="mt-3" colspan="2">
            <table class="table-borderless">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="A" type="button" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">A</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer1 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="B" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">B</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer2 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <div class="input-group mb-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="C" onclick="clickFunc(this.id)">C</button>
                            <input type="text" asp-for=@Model.Answer3 class="form-control" placeholder=""
                                   aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input name="TrueAnswer" id="TrueAnswer" hidden />
            <button type="submit" onclick="clickSub()" class="btn btn-success" asp-action="QuestionMaker" asp-controller="Teacher" formmethod="post">Kaydet</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</tbody>
```

js:

```
function clickFunc(answerId) {
    $("#TrueAnswer").val(answerId);
    $("#myForm").submit();
}
```